# Hex - Search by bytes to get Offset & Search by Offset to get Bytes

Tags: go, hex

just currently prototyping a little software and currently stuck. I'm trying to create a little program that'll edit a `.bin` file, and for this I will need to do the following:

- Get Bytes by Searching for Offset
- Get Offset by searching for Bytes
- Write/Update `.bin` file

I usually use the program `HxD` to do this manually, but want to get a small automated process in place.

Using [`hex.EncodeToString`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiBJR.png) returns what I want as the output (Like `HxD`) however I can't find a way to search for the values by bytes and offests

Could anyone help or have suggestions?

Comment: I fail to quite parse the question. Do you mean searching the actual (raw) contents of a file for a certain sequence of bytes? And do you mean locating data at a specific offset in a file and reading a certain number of bytes beginning at that offset?

Comment: I mean, to me, it looks like you're mixing presentation (of bytes to the user) and working with bytes as the contents of a file.

Comment: @kostix So for example, I need the ability to Search for say, 00 87 and grab the offset for this in my file (Which would be 00000014). And I also need to be able to search for the Offset 00000014 and see what the data is at this offset (00 87)

Comment: OK, I've posted an answer. Hope it will get you going; feel free to ask specific questions if you'll have any problems with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

OK, "searching of an offset" is a misnomer because if you have an offset and a medium which supports random access, you just "seek" the known offset there; for files, see [`os.File.Seek`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Seek).

Searching is more complex: it consists of converting the user input into something searchable and, well, the searching itself.

Conversion is the process of translation of the human operator's imput to a slice of bytes — for instance, you'd need to convert a string "00 87" to a slice of bytes, `[]byte{00, 87}`.
Such conversion can be done using, say, [`encoding/hex.Decode`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/hex#DecodeString) after removing any whitespace, which can be done using a multitude of ways.

Searching the file given a slice of bytes can be either simple of complex.
If a file is small (a couple megabytes, on today's hardware), you can just slurp it into memory (for instance, using [`io.ReadAll`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReadAll)) and do a simple search using [`bytes.Index`](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Index).

If a file is big, the complexity of the task quickly escalates.
For instance, you could read the file from its beginning to its end using chunks of some sensible size and search for your byte slice in each of them.
But you'd need to watch out for two issues: the slice to search should be smaller than each of such chunks, and two adjacent chunks might contain the sequence to be found positioned right across their "sides" — so that the Nth chunk contains the first part of the pattern at its end and the N+1th chunk contains the rest of it at its beginning.

There exist more advanced approaches to such searching — for instance, using so-called "memory-mapped files" but I'd speculate it's a bit too early to tread these lands, given your question.